# Error initializing Stripe settings: Instance of 'StripeConfigException'

Tags: flutter, web, stripe-payments, payment

I am getting the following error based on the code which is provided below. How can one fix this problem?

Error initializing Stripe settings: Instance of 'StripeConfigException'

Exception during payment: Instance of 'StripeConfigException'

dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3  throw*

packages/flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart 31:7                                 get publishableKey

packages/flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart 105:25                               applySettings

packages/flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart 647:25                               [_awaitForSettings]

packages/flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart 453:11                               initPaymentSheet

dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54           runBody

art-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5           _async

packages/flutter_stripe/src/stripe.dart 446:54                               initPaymentSheet

packages/Palaz/payment/cart_checkout_stripe.dart 132:31                      makePayment

dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50

dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                         runUnary

dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18                                   handleValue

dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 846:44                                   handleValueCallback

dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 875:13                                   _propagateToListeners

dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 647:5                                    [_completeWithValue]

dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 721:7                                    callback

dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                             _microtaskLoop

dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                              _startMicrotaskLoop

dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:Palaz/env.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  try {
    Stripe.publishableKey = '...';
    Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'merchant.flutter.stripe.test';
    Stripe.urlScheme = 'flutterstripe';
    await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('Error applying Stripe publishable key: $e');
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Stripe Payment',
      theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: PaymentsPage(totalPrice: 10.0),
    );
  }
}

class PaymentsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final double totalPrice;

  const PaymentsPage({Key? key, required this.totalPrice}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PaymentsPage> createState() => _PaymentsPageState();
}

class _PaymentsPageState extends State<PaymentsPage> {
  late GlobalKey<FormState> paymentForm;
  Map<String, dynamic>? paymentIntentData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    paymentForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    initializeStripeSettings();
  }



  void initializeStripeSettings() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.applySettings(

      );
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error initializing Stripe settings: $e');
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Stripe Payment'),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      ),
      body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Form(
      key: paymentForm,
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (paymentForm.currentState!.validate()) {
                makePayment(
                  amount: (widget.totalPrice * 100).toString(),
                  currency: "USD",
                );
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Make Payment'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Future<void> makePayment({required String amount, required String currency}) async {
    try {
      paymentIntentData = await createPaymentIntent(widget.totalPrice.toString(), currency);

      const gpay = PaymentSheetGooglePay(
    merchantCountryCode: "US",
    currencyCode: "USD",
    testEnv: true,
      );
      if (paymentIntentData != null) {
    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        googlePay: gpay,
        merchantDisplayName: 'Adiwele',
        paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['client_secret'],
        customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntentData!['ephemeralKey'],
        customFlow: true,
        allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true, // set this to true
      ),
    );
    displayPaymentSheet();
      }
    } catch (e, s) {
      debugPrint('Exception during payment: $e\n$s');
    }
  }

  displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet().then(
        (value) {},
      );
    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Payment failed: ${e.error.localizedMessage}');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('An unexpected error occurred: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createPaymentIntent(String amount, String currency) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'amount': amount,
    'currency': currency,
    'payment_method_types[]': 'card'
      };
      var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
    body: body,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ...',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
      );

      return jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return {};
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you have the chance to run the Stripe Flutter example project ? and use it a base project?
https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example